# Correlated double sampling

Tags: signal, signal-processing

Talking about analog offset compensation and offset temperature drift, which is the max signal frequency acceptable to apply correlated double sampling ?

I know it is for low frequency but I don't know the high limit.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More elaborate CDS circuits are needed to compensate for gain mismatch and nonlinearity in the circuits are required. But if linear then CDS works well.

However,  if gain drops with rising frequency used, then more complex CDS compensation is needed.

Comment: I am talking about for a very low signal bandwidth  50 to 300 HZ .

Comment: if BW yields flat gain, then you only need to be concerned about nonlinearity, like memory effects caused by storage hysteresis and neglect IFF, SNR or B/W ratio is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Assuming correlated double-sampling is used in imagers to reduce the dark-current noise, or mismatches in pixel leakages, these pixels are read out well under 1uS.